# Cannot post Token from Client

Tags: node.js, jwt

Frontend Code

```
<script>
      const formDOM = document.querySelector(".form");
      const btnSubmitDOM = document.querySelector(".btn-submit");

      // get token form server
      formDOM.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const email = document.querySelector("#email").value;
        const password = document.querySelector("#password").value;

        try {
          const { data } = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/login",
            { email, password }
          );
          console.log("token", data.token);
          localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });

      // after submit, if authenticated, goes to protective route
      btnSubmitDOM.addEventListener("click", async () => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        console.log("toekn when press", token);

        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/inventories", {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          });
          location.assign("/inventories");
        } catch (error) {
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Here is the backend code

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
    res.send("Auth route - Unauthenticated Error");
  }
  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  console.log("token is ", token);

  try {
    const payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secret');
    // console.log(payload);

    // attached to the inventories route
    req.user = {
      userId: payload.userId,
      email: payload.email,
    };
    // console.log(req.user)
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

module.exports = auth;
```

Here is the error from server side

```
token is  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2MzY4ZjFiM2U1ODJlYmQ1MjJkODI4MGEiLCJlbWFpbCI6Imt5YXdAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY3ODI3NzIzLCJleHAiOjE2NzA0MTk3MjN9.rptgRrYB4TrLQCxbB18JqMHd05LSox-LQuiLJS0L2Gw

/Users/kyawmyo/Desktop/software-development/nodejs-&-vanilajs-projects/inventories/middleware/authentication.js:8
  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
```

I try to test with postman, all working fine.
But I send request from client side, it is error, I cannot figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Did you look at the headers?

Comment: Can you console.log the "req" and the "req.headers" to see what is in there? Furthermore: It looks to me on first sight that you are trying to do a "split" (which is a string function) on an object, which might cause your problem.

Comment: authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2MzY4ZjFiM2U1ODJlYmQ1MjJkODI4MGEiLCJlbWFpbCI6Imt5YXdAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjY3ODI4ODc1LCJleHAiOjE2NzA0MjA4NzV9.-0D64-TviCY9xlnVa1G28eubRiWvqmxvPnMrw-JnBPg',